# Devise: override output to custom json on wrong token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

```
I want to show all models by request http://server/api/art/show.json?auth_token=correct_token
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    arts = Article.all
    render :json => {:state => {:code => 0}, :data => arts}
  end

  def new

  end
end
```

If token is correct then i recieve data and it's ok, but if token isn't correct i have:

{
"email": "",
"password": null
}

```
In logs i see that it redirected me to http://server/users/sign_in.json
```

WHY?? Where i can override this behaviour? I want to display custom json in this case

P.S. i'm using token auth without sessions

Comment: This blog post may be useful: http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/

Comment: I saw it, i have similar code and can't find why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom failureApp helped me.

class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if request.format
      json_failure
    else
      super
    end
  end

def json_failure
    self.status = 401
    self.content_type = 'json'
    self.response_body = "{'state' : {'code' : 1, 'messages'  = ['authentication error'] } }" // <- this line did help me
  end
end